# Text game If statement trouble

Tags: java

I am making a text game and am stuck with a game breaking bug or it could be because I am only using this to learn some java that I may just be doing it incorrectly here is the section I am stuck where I know the bug is.

What is meant to happen is that it will decide weather the user has a sword or armour and therefore change the options depending on that but it only runs the first print command unless I manually set either of the hasSword or hasArmour variables which then it will run all of the way through.

```
static void shop()
{
    System.out.println("As you enter the shop you check how much gold you have left. As you count it you find you have " + gold + " gold to spend this time!");

    if(hasSword && hasArmour == true)
    {
        System.out.println("Looks like the shop is all bought out!!\n1. Back");

        in = input.nextInt();

        if(in == 1)
        {
            city();
        }
    }
    else if(hasSword == true)
    {
        System.out.println("1. Armour 50 gold");
        System.out.println("2. Exit");

        in = input.nextInt();

        if(in == 1)
        {
            if(gold >= 50)
            {
                hasArmour = true;
                hp = 20;
                gold = gold - 50;
                city();
            }
            else if(gold < 50)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry you do not have enough gold");
                shop();
            }
        }
        else if(in == 2)
        {
            city();
        }
    }
    else if(hasArmour == true)
    {
        System.out.println("1. Sword 10 gold");
        System.out.println("2. Exit");

        in = input.nextInt();

        if(in == 1)
        {
            if(gold >= 10)
            {
                hasSword = true;
                dmg = 10;
                gold = gold - 10;
                city();
            }
            else if(gold <10)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry you do not have enough gold");
                shop();
            }
        }
        else if(in == 2)
        {
            city();
        }
    }
    else if(hasSword && hasArmour == false)
    {
        System.out.println("1. Sword 10 gold");
        System.out.println("2. Armour 50 gold");
        System.out.println("3. Back");

        in = input.nextInt();

        if(in == 1)
        {
            if(gold >= 10)
            {
                hasSword = true;
                dmg = 10;
                gold = gold - 10;
                city();
            }
            else if(gold <10)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry you do not have enough gold");
                shop();
            }
        }
        else if(in == 2)
        {
            if(gold >= 50)
            {
                hasArmour = true;
                hp = 20;
                gold = gold - 50;
                city();
            }
            else if(gold < 50)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry you do not have enough gold");
                shop();
            }
        }
        else if(in == 3)
        {
            city();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it would also be epic if you could say what was wrong so that i do not repeat the mistake in the future.

Comment: Here's my code.  Find my bug.

Comment: Maybe if you didn't use `<boolean_variable> == <true/false>` in your `if` statements you wouldn't have a bug. Also, `&&` has higher precedence than `==`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: haha no that's not what I meant. I have been trying for ages and cannot work out what is wrong and therefore I asked for help so I can find out if I am doing the if statement wrong because I really have no clue.

Comment: The program doesn't even get to the first print. it does not run the print at all and if i change the hasSword or hasArmour to true it works so I am completely lost.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, the Q&A site where we love awesome questions :) A good way to find bugs would be to wrap your code in a minimal example. E.g. a dummy class with `main` method calling `shop()` - without context it's like shooting blindfolded at puppies out of a F1 racer.
However in regards to your last comment: Have you declared your Booleans before? If it doesn't run do you get an error messsage?

Comment: Please describe the difference between what's happening, and what's supposed to.

Comment: @yoshi yes the booleans are declared and i will give that a try thankyou for the help

Comment: @DaveNewton what is happening is that it runs the first print command and then stops and what is supposed to happen is that it is meant to display 3 options in the shop (sword, armour and back) depending on what has already been purchased for example if hasSword is set to true then it should only display armour and back and not the sword as they already have one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `hasArmor`and `hasSword` are `false` by default if you don't declare them explicitly.
The problem lies within your last `else if` condition.
You wrote

```
else if(hasSword && hasArmour == false)
```

Since `==` has a higher precedence as `&&` this condition is interpreted as

```
(hasSword && (hasArmour == false))
```

and because of the short-circuiting mechanism in Java, as soon as the first part of the condition (namely `hasSword`) is false, the whole condition is considered false and your block is not executed.

To get the block executed, you have to write it like so:

```
else if((hasSword && hasArmour) == false)
```

Now the logical operator is evaluated first, then it is checked, if it is false, and your block is executed.

To prevent confusions with conditions, you could structure your code a little differently. But in the end, this will improve the readability, while the behaviour will stay the same.

```
if(hasSword) {
    if(hasArmor) {
        // Your first block
    }
    else {
        // Your second block
    }
}
else {
    if(hasArmor) {
        // Your third block
    }
    else {
       // Your fourth block
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much that was exactly what i was looking for the solution and then why.